# Where should I store the RESTful data in Android?

Tags: android, rest

I need to build an android application that communicates with a REST WebService. All operations will be performed online and there are few objects/data that need to be stored in the device memory. I run through RESTDroid but it seems to be "too much" for my needs. Should I store the objects in the file system/sd card? What are the advantages/disavantages of this approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many same objects, that you receive from your web service, you should use SQLite  database. If you have few objects you can serialize it and store in file or serialize it as JSON for example and store in SharedRreferences. I dont know the best way for you, but for me it would be SQLite database or SharedPreferences.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you can look into this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)  in which he explained so beautifully to store SMALL  RESTful data